# How to avoid overriding 'title' of the header in TabNavigator and its children screens? (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to set the title of the TabNavigator as 'Stylebook' with a button.

However, the screens which are children of TabNavigator change the 'title'. I think it's overriding the 'title' prop. How can I avoid it?

[image]

This is TabNavigator (my TabBar is in the StackNavigator)

```
export default TabNavigator(
 {
   Category: {
     screen: StylebookCategoryScreen
   },
   All: {
     screen: StylebookAllScreen
   }
 } ,{
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Stylebook',
    headerRight: (
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Wardrobe')}
        title="Wardrobe"
      />
    )
 })
});
```

StylebookAllScreen is almost identical with StylebookCategoryScreen.

```
class StylebookAllScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
   title:'All'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>StylebookALLScreen</Text>
        <Text>StylebookALLScreen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default StylebookAllScreen;
```

I can also change whole structure of the navigator, if I can fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: I think if you remove the `title` from the tab screens, this won't happen. The tabs get the name you define in the navigator by default, so that should be fine.

Comment: @NimrodArgov That was close, but not right. When I remove `title` from tab screens, those titles are changed to 'STYLEBOOK';                        
               'all' -> 'stylebook', 'category' -> 'stylebook'.

Comment: Is your hierarchy `StackNavigator -> TabNavigator -> Component`?

Comment: It's `TabNavigator -> StackNavigator -> TabNavigator -> Component`. Um.. it's similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your `StylebookAllScreen` component into a [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack) and then put that into your `TabNavigator`. Putting it into a `StackNavigator` allows you to set `props` like

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: "Stylebook",
    }),
```

With `headerLeft` or `headerRight` you can add a `Component` (such as a `Button` to the left/right of your headline.

Try something like this:

```
const StylebookStack = StackNavigator({
    StylebookAllScreen: {
        screen: Map,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: "Stylebook",
            headerTitleStyle: {
                ....
            },
        }),
    },
});
```

And then put that into your `TabNavigator`

```
export default TabNavigator(
 {
   Category: {
     screen: StylebookCategoryScreen
   },
   All: {
     screen: StylebookStack // <--- HERE
   }
 } ,{
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Stylebook',
    headerRight: (
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Wardrobe')}
        title="Wardrobe"
      />
    )
 })
});
```

Comment: I think you can solve this problem (+200 bounty) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930049/how-to-reset-tabnavigator-when-user-logs-out-from-other-screen